How can I get each page of "Page Break Preview" in Excel using Python?
Problem
I'm trying to get each page of "Page Break Preview". Precisely speaking, I need to know which cells Page 1 contains, which cells Page 2 contains and so on.
Could you teach me how to realize this functionality in Python 3.12? I tried openpyxl, but other libraries are welcome too.
Example (What I Tried)
I find openpyxl has print_area variable, but this variable only returns the whole print area, which contains all pages, so I can't know which page each cell belongs to.
As you can see the code and the screenshot, the result is A1:R50, which contains both Page 1 and Page 2.
In this example, the expected result is something like {'Page1': 'A1:I50', 'Page2':'J1:R50'}.
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename="./sample_loader_data/sample.xlsx", 
                         read_only=True, 
                         data_only=True, 
                         )
workbook.worksheets[0].print_area # Result: "'Test worksheet'!$A$1:$R$50"



@moken or is there a way to get the number of pages in a worksheet?

Why are you looking at the private variable, _print_area and it's private for a reason, when you really want to look at the page breaks?

As commented here, this is not possible with openpyxl
UPDATE: As @dmjy correctly answered, it is now possible with openpyxl.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
import re

workbook = load_workbook(filename="Demo.xlsx")

vertical_breaks = [0]+[page_break.id for page_break in workbook.worksheets[0].col_breaks.brk]
horizontal_breaks = [0]+[page_break.id for page_break in workbook.worksheets[0].row_breaks.brk]

last_cell = workbook.worksheets[0].dimensions.split(":")[1]
last_col = ''.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', last_cell))
last_row = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', last_cell))

pages = {}
cnt=1
for v, v_break in enumerate(vertical_breaks):
    for h, h_break in enumerate(horizontal_breaks):
        start_col = get_column_letter(vertical_breaks[v]+1)
        start_row = horizontal_breaks[h]+1
        end_col = get_column_letter(vertical_breaks[v+1]) if v+1 < len(vertical_breaks) else last_col
        end_row = horizontal_breaks[h+1] if h+1 < len(horizontal_breaks) else last_row
        pages[f"Page{cnt}"] = f"{start_col}{start_row}:{end_col}{end_row}"
        cnt+=1

print(pages)

For this example

It correctly outputs
{'Page1': 'A1:F27', 'Page2': 'A28:F54', 'Page3': 'G1:N27', 'Page4': 'G28:N54', 'Page5': 'O1:T27', 'Page6': 'O28:T54'}

Alternative with xlrd for .xls files.
import xlrd

def num_to_excel_col(n):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("Number must be positive")
    result = ""
    while True:
        if n > 26:
            n, r = divmod(n - 1, 26)
            result = chr(r + ord('A')) + result
        else:
            return chr(n + ord('A') - 1) + result


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Demo.xls", formatting_info=True)
worksheet = workbook.sheets()[0]

vertical_breaks = worksheet.vertical_page_breaks
vertical_breaks.insert(0, (0,0,0))
horizontal_breaks = worksheet.horizontal_page_breaks
horizontal_breaks.insert(0, (0,0,0))

last_row = worksheet.nrows
last_col = worksheet.ncols

pages = {}
cnt=1
for v, v_break in enumerate(vertical_breaks):
    for h, h_break in enumerate(horizontal_breaks):
        start_col = num_to_excel_col(vertical_breaks[v][0]+1)
        start_row = horizontal_breaks[h][0]+1
        end_col = num_to_excel_col(vertical_breaks[v+1][0] if v+1 < len(vertical_breaks) else last_col)
        end_row = horizontal_breaks[h+1][0] if h+1 < len(horizontal_breaks) else last_row
        pages[f"Page{cnt}"] = f"{start_col}{start_row}:{end_col}{end_row}"
        cnt+=1

print(pages)

{'Page1': 'A1:F27', 'Page2': 'A28:F54', 'Page3': 'G1:N27', 'Page4': 'G28:N54', 'Page5': 'O1:T27', 'Page6': 'O28:T54'}

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter openpyxl has a function that is similar to @DaSt's num_to_excel_col .

@DaSt's answer is great and the only problem is xlrd is incompatible with xlsx.
I get an inspiration from the answer, which uses worksheet.vertical_page_breaks and worksheet.horizontal_page_breaks
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.pagebreak.html
I find the latest openpyxl (3.1.3) actually has pageBreak module.
pageBreak is accessible by row_breaks and col_breaks.
workbook.worksheet[0].row_breaks.brk
workbook.worksheet[0].col_breaks.brk

By combining the way I wrote above with @DaSt's answer, I can get the expected answer.

Great catch! I updated my answer to also include openpyxl.
Feel free to accept it, unless you need further improvements :)
